# How to do compare-and-increment different locations with in memory MVCC?

Tags: concurrency, database-theory, databases

I'm reading the paper [An Empirical Evaluation of
In-Memory Multi-Version Concurrency Control](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jarulraj/papers/2017.mvcc.vldb.pdf) which is about implementations of MVCC for in-memory databases. **Section 3.3** on **Two-phase Locking (MV2PL)** says:

> To perform a read operation on a tuple `A`, the DBMS searches for a
>   visible version by comparing a transaction’s `T-id` with the tuples’
>   `begin-ts` field.  If it finds a valid version, then the DBMS
>   increments that tuple’s `read-cnt` field if its `txn-id` field is
>   equal to zero (meaning that no other transaction holds the write lock)

Here is the image in **Figure 2c**:
[image: MV2PL]

The confusion point is about how it actually does this operation atomically: **Read location A (`txn-id`), if its value is equal to 0 then increment location B (`read-cnt`)**

Atomic operation in C/C++ does `compare-and-swap` only for a single memory location, however, in this case we are dealing with two memory locations. Is there any other CPU intrinsic for this operation, or another trick is employed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question directly from paper authors, and they replied to me:

> `txn-id` and `read-cnt` are 4-bytes each (not 8 bytes as I thought before), thus it is possible to compare-and-swap in one step.